# Slide out menu - When switching back to original controller, Nav bar disappears

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationitem, slidingmenu, swrevealviewcontroller

I have a slide out menu in my app, and just to let you know, I'm new to iOS/Swift, so if I don't explain it well, or use the correct terms, that's why.

I use the SWRevealViewController library for my sliding out menu.

The only code i use from that for all my View Controllers is

```
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
```

The issue basically is, when the app first opens, it shows my navigation item's title and all that on ViewController1(default view), but when using the slide out menu to go to ViewController2 or 3, and then going back to the ViewController1, the whole navigation bar/item disappears.

I tried to use something like `nav_item.title = "whatever"` within viewDidLoad(), but that doesn't work, as far as when i switch back to the first view. The funny thing is, if i programmatically change the title doing that, it changes when it first loads but when i change to View2 and change back to View1, just disappears.

Here are a few images of what i mean, if i didn't explain it well enough, because like i said i'm still new. The development of my app is coming along pretty well because i'm going off my android version i've had done for a while.

[image: a busy cat]
Here is when it first loads, title and all. Notice, my background color doesn't overlap or change the top part for the time and battery, which becomes a problem with the later view.

[image: a busy cat]
Switched to a different view using my slide out menu.

[image: a busy cat]
Switching back to to the original view, the nav item disappears and the background color extends to the full view, overlapping the battery status and time

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Stuck at something similar.

Answer (score 2):

How does your Storyboard look like? This is how I usually do it.

[image]